# Filter through database results using WHERE

Tags: ruby, database, search, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have an array containing URL paths, I want to be able to search in my database in a table which one of the fields (labelled "URL") for the URLs specified in the array.

So I have a simplified version of what I want to achieve.

```
urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3", "url4", ... ]
urlsInDB = []
results = Link.all
urls.each() do |url|
 if not results.where(:url=>url).blank?
   urlsInDB << url
 end
end
```

However I know that you cannot call ".where" on a set of results obtained by ".all". I want to do it this way so that the database is only ever queried once not for each URL in ***urls*** as this can have length ***n*** and that would require ***n*** queries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, you'd do this by saying:

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE url IN ('url1', 'url2', 'url3');
```

You can do this with ActiveRecord by saying:

```
Link.where(:url => ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'])
```

If you just want to get an array of URLs that matched, say:

```
Link.select(:url).where(:url => ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']).map(&:url)
# SQL: SELECT url FROM links WHERE url IN ('url1', 'url2', 'url3')
# => ['url1', 'url2']
```

Comment: This would be better served with the new Rails `pluck` method. Loading an entire model and extracting a single value is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Why would this answer be accepted while there was a more efficient and up to date one offered?

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplified version assuming you're using activerecord and on the latest rails version.  Make sure to use `pluck` since it is better than iterating twice using `map`

```
urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3", "url4", ... ]
urlsInDB = Link.where(:url => urls).pluck(:url)
```